# Wordpres erro 404 - Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: wordpress

Começou aparece essa mensagem no meu site wordpress.

404 Not Found

The requested URL /.html was not found on this server.

O estranho é que quando retiro o www e tento acessar o mesmo por um subdominio ele fica acessivel.

com o "www" aparece a mensagem acima. sem ele o site fica acessivel.

Comment: "Começou a aparecer" cheira a hacker, não? Ou começou a aparecer depois da atualização do X pro Y?

Comment: Já verificou o seu '.htacess'? Provável que tenha sido alterado, já que os subdominíos estão operando normalmente.

Comment: como estão definidas as globais `WP_HOME` e `WP_SITEURL` no seu `wp-config.php` ?